# "RewriteEngine not allowed here" .htaccess error using XAMPP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am trying to configure Apache to allow .htaccess Rewrite rules. I am using XAMPP to run Apache locally. However, I keep getting 500 errors. I have been Googling for several hours about this and tried all the common solutions, so please read my entire post so as not to duplicate solutions I have already tried.

When I check the apache error log the error reads:

> "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/websites/demo2/.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here".

Almost every other person I could find that was having this issue solved it by:

1. Un-commenting the `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` command in the httpd.conf
2. Changing `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All`

However neither of these solutions have worked for me. I still get the 500 error. My issues sounds identical to this thread http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1786841 , but that issue was never solved. I think the error might be the location of my .htaccess file, but I don't know. Any insight is much appreciated!

Btw, here is my .htaccess file. It is a Wordpress install:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xampp/websites/demo2/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /xampp/websites/demo2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and here is my httpd.conf file

```
    #
    # This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
    # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
    # See  for detailed information.
    # In particular, see 
    # 
    # for a discussion of each configuration directive.
    #
    # Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
    # what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
    # consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
    #
    # Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
    # of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
    # server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
    # with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/foo.log"
    # with ServerRoot set to "/xampp/apache" will be interpreted by the
    # server as "/xampp/apache/logs/foo.log".
    #
    # NOTE: Where filenames are specified, you must use forward slashes
    # instead of backslashes (e.g., "c:/apache" instead of "c:\apache").
    # If a drive letter is omitted, the drive on which httpd.exe is located
    # will be used by default.  It is recommended that you always supply
    # an explicit drive letter in absolute paths to avoid confusion.

    #
    # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
    # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
    #
    # Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
    # ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to point the LockFile directive
    # at a local disk.  If you wish to share the same ServerRoot for multiple
    # httpd daemons, you will need to change at least LockFile and PidFile.
    #
    ServerRoot "/xampp/apache"

    #
    # Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
    # ports, instead of the default. See also the 
    # directive.
    #
    # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
    # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
    #
    #Listen 0.0.0.0:80
    #Listen [::]:80
    Listen 80

    # Default charset UTF8
    # AddDefaultCharset utf-8

    #
    # Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
    #
    # To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
    # have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
    # directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
    # Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
    # to be loaded here.
    #
    # Example:
    # LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
    #

    LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
    LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
    LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
    LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
    LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
    LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
    #LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
    #LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
    LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
    #LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
    #LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
    LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
    #LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
    #LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
    LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
    #LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
    #LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
    LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
    LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
    #LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
    LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
    LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
    #LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
    #LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
    #LoadModule case_filter_module modules/mod_case_filter.so
    #LoadModule case_filter_in_module modules/mod_case_filter_in.so
    #LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
    LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
    #LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
    #LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
    #LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
    LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
    #LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
    #LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
    LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
    #LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
    #LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
    #LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
    LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
    #LoadModule example_module modules/mod_example.so
    #LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
    #LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
    #LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so # did not work at runtime
    #LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
    #LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
    LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
    #LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
    #LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
    LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
    LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
    LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
    #LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
    #LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
    LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
    #LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
    LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
    LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
    #LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
    LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
    #LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
    #LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
    #LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
    #LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
    LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
    #LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
    LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
    LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
    #LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
    #LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
    #LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
    #LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
    #LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
    #LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

    
    
    #
    # If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
    # httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
    #
    # User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
    # It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
    # running httpd, as with most system services.
    #
    User daemon
    Group daemon

    
    

    # 'Main' server configuration
    #
    # The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
    # server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
    #  definition.  These values also provide defaults for
    # any  containers you may define later in the file.
    #
    # All of these directives may appear inside  containers,
    # in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
    # virtual host being defined.
    #

    #
    # ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
    # e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
    # as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
    #
    ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost

    #
    # ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
    # This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
    # it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
    #
    # If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
    #
    ServerName localhost:80

    #
    # DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
    # documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
    # symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
    #
    DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs"

    #
    # Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
    # to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
    # directory (and its subdirectories). 
    #
    # First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
    # features.  
    #
    
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    


    # XAMPP: We disable operating system specific optimizations for a listening 
    # socket by the http protocol here. IE 64 bit make problems without this.  
    AcceptFilter http none

    #
    # Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
    # particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
    # you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
    # below.
    #

    #
    # This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
    #
    
        #
        # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
        # or any combination of:
        #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
        #
        # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
        # doesn't give it to you.
        #
        # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
        # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
        # for more information.
        #
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

        #
        # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
        # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
        #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
        #
        AllowOverride All

        #
        # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
        #
        Require all granted

    

    #
    # DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
    # is requested.
    #
    
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                       default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                       home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
    

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
    # viewed by Web clients. 
    #
    
        Require all denied
    

    #
    # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
    # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a 
    # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
    # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a 
    # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
    #
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

    #ScriptLog "logs/cgi.log"

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    #
    LogLevel warn

    
        #
        # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
        # a CustomLog directive (see below).
        #
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

        
          # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
          LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
        

        #
        # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
        # If you do not define any access logfiles within a 
        # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
        # define per- access logfiles, transactions will be
        # logged therein and *not* in this file.
        #
        #CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

        #
        # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
        # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
        #
        CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
    

    
        #
        # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
        # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
        # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
        # Example:
        # Redirect permanent /foo http://localhost/bar

        #
        # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
        # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
        # Example:
        # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
        #
        # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
        # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
        # need to provide a  section to allow access to
        # the filesystem path.

        #
        # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
        # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
        # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
        # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
        # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
        # directives as to Alias.
        #
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/xampp/cgi-bin/"

    

    
        #
        # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
        # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
        #
        #Scriptsock "logs/cgi.sock"
    

    #
    # "/xampp/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
    # CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
    #
    
        AllowOverride All
        Options None
        Require all granted
    


    
        #
        # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
        # filename extension to MIME-type.
        #
        TypesConfig "conf/mime.types"

        #
        # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
        # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
        #
        #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
        #
        # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
        # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
        #
        #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
        #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
        #
        # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
        # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
        #
        AddType application/x-compress .Z
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

        #
        # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
        # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
        # or added with the Action directive (see below)
        #
        # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
        # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
        #
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp

        # For type maps (negotiated resources):
        #AddHandler type-map var

        #
        # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
        #
        # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
        # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
        #
        AddType text/html .shtml
        AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    

    
        #
        # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
        # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
        # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
        #
        MIMEMagicFile "conf/magic"
    

    #
    # Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
    # 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
    #
    # Some examples:
    #ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
    #ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
    #ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
    #ErrorDocument 402 http://localhost/subscription_info.html
    #

    #
    # EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
    # memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall is used to deliver
    # files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
    # be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
    # filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
    # broken on your system.
    #
    #EnableMMAP off
    #EnableSendfile off

    # Supplemental configuration
    #
    # The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
    # included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
    # the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
    # necessary.

    # XAMPP specific settings
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

    # Server-pool management (MPM specific)
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf"

    # Multi-language error messages
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf"

    # Fancy directory listings
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf"

    # Language settings
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf"

    # User home directories
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf"

    # Real-time info on requests and configuration
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-info.conf"

    # Virtual hosts
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"

    # Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
    # Attention! WEB_DAV is a security risk without a new userspecific configuration for a secure authentifcation 
    # Include "conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf"

    # Implements a proxy/gateway for Apache.
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-proxy.conf"

    # Various default settings
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-default.conf"

    # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf"
    #
    # Note: The following must must be present to support
    #       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
    #       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
    #
    
        SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
        SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    

    # Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
    #
    #Include etc/extra/proxy-html.conf
    #

    # AJP13 Proxy
    
    
    Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
```

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making your config changes? can you show your .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes, I restarted Apache. I just added my .htaccess to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Are you 100% sure there is no other AllowOverride elsewhere, overriding your setting?

Comment: Also would be helpful to see the httpd.conf

Comment: There are 3 instances of `AllowOverride` in the httpd.conf file and I have updated all of them and restarted Apache, but the error persists.

Comment: I just added my httpd.conf to the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set AllowOverride to All in conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf.

Comment: That solved the problem! Seems strange that no one else has run into this problem. I also had to change the `RewriteBase` in my .htaccess file to `/xampp/htdocs/` instead of the one generated by Wordpress, but everything is working great now. Thanks!

Comment: That did not worked out for me. I installed Apache and PHP manually.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1 )=> open file ...\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

2 )=> find line "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so"

3 )=> if here is a # before this line remove it.(remove comment)

i hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project exemple
C:\xampp 8.2\htdocs\UniversSocial

**rename the htaccess.txt to .htaccess**
yes you have to remove .txt and put a . at start of name

why ? when you extract windows change to file name to a default file wich is.txt

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E15av.png)

Comment: of course you have to do this too


( 1 )=> open file ...\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf


( 2 )=> find line "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so"


( 3 )=> if here is a # before this line remove it.(remove comment)

( 4 )  Replace all AllowOverride None by AllowOverride All