# RewriteEngine not allowed here (Apache2)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I used a plain config and added

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

DocumentRoot "C:/Projects/web/"

Alias / "C:/Projects/web/" 
<Directory "C:/Projects/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My .htaccess looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(..)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(..)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&cat=$2&sub=$3
```

The regex are correct. In the logfiles I got:

```
[Fri Oct 28 19:37:50.483153 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5508:tid 1056] [client ::1:49898] C:/Projects/web/.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here
[Fri Oct 28 19:37:51.385204 2016] [core:alert] [pid 5508:tid 1056] [client ::1:49899] C:/Projects/web/.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here
```

I tried to get more verbose output by setting `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8` and `LogLevel debug` but it doesn't help.

Comment: I think that the solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995545/htaccess-rewriteengine-not-allowed-here) in another post

Comment: I already set **AllowOverride All** in the <Directory> Section

Comment: did you read all post, comments and responses? There are a lot info in that post, please, read it, it is not only AllowOverride All

Comment: Yes I read everything and some other posts with the same topic before I had opened my own.

Comment: Did you restart apache when you enabled the rewrite module?

Comment: Yes, I did restart apache.

Comment: @MarcS82 do you tried enable the module instead add this line to the virtual host?
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Comment: I mean using the command a2enmod

Comment: I'm on windows. I had mod_rewrite working on another website some time ago so the module should work correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["RewriteEngine not allowed here" .htaccess error using XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277986/rewriteengine-not-allowed-here-htaccess-error-using-xampp)

Comment: Have you searched, case-insensitively for *all* instances of `AllowOverride` in *all* configuration files? Try [grepWin](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html).